# Look up and matching of string between 2 files

Tags: perl

I have two files in zipped format

**file1.gz**

```
a2345
b1212
11212
f1212
derer
...
...
..
01234
```

**file2.gz**

```
g,a2345,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,a,v,c
f,b1212,2,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3
d,f1212,7,8,a,b,c,w,e,r,t,y
....
....
```

I have to read file1.gz line by line and do a lookup in each line of file2.gz and if it matches then re-direct to one more file called file 3.

Please remember my **file1.gz has 1 million lines** and **file2.gz has 5 million lines** and so I need some work around in perl so that it consumes low resource in my Solaris server.

If a perl script can be worked by reading the content in zip file that would be of really great help.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about how to open the gzip files for reading in Perl:

if you have the Compress::Zlib module, then

```
use Compress::Zlib;

$f1 = gzopen( "file1.gz", "r" );
$f2 = gzopen( "file2.gz", "r" );

$bytes = $f1->gzreadline( $line );
```

etc... do

```
perldoc Compress::Zlib
```

to see the documentation.

Without that module, you can still do

```
open( F1, "gzip -dc file1.gz |" );
open( F2, "gzip -dc file2.gz |" );
```

which has a little more overhead because you're creating additional gzip processes to read the files.

Comment: Is it possible to full write up of the script as i am rookie in PERL

Comment: How much are you paying? :-]  I can't, sorry, but maybe someone else could.